# Question about derivative of scalar function of matrix wrt scalar

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, differential

Can someone help me understand the meaning of this derivative where i have a scalar, wich is a function of a matrix, when i take it with respect to another scalar?
\begin{align}
y =  \mathrm{ln}|At+B|,
\end{align}
where $A$ and $B$ are matrices, $B$ is invertible, $t$ and $y$ are scalars.

With $X = At+B$ the function become
\begin{align}
y =  \mathrm{ln}|X|.
\end{align}
The differentials are
\begin{align}
 dy 
 &= d\ \mathrm{ln}|X|\cr
 &= \mathrm{Tr}(X^{-1} dX)\cr
 &= X^{-T}:dX\cr
 dX &= (dAt+Adt+dB).
\end{align}

Since i only ask about $t \implies dX = Adt$. Substituting $dX$ in $dy$ led to
\begin{align}
 dy 
 &= X^{-T}:dX\cr
 &= X^{-T}:Adt\cr
 &= A^TX^{-T}:dt.\cr
\end{align}

Therefore the gradient is
\begin{align}
 \frac{dy}{dt} 
 &= A^TX^{-T}\cr
 &= A^T(At+B)^{-T},\cr
\end{align}
where the answer is an matrix for any $t$.
I was expecting a scalar as a result.

How this answer can be interpreted? There is something wrong with my development?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let $\gamma=(X^{-T}:A),\,$ then at one point in the derivation you had $\,dy = \gamma\,dt.\,$ Stop there and notice that this means that $\gamma$ is the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @greg comment that pointed out my mistake the correct answer is
\begin{align}
 dy 
 &= d\ \mathrm{ln}|X|\cr
 &= \mathrm{Tr}(X^{-1} dX)\cr
 &= \mathrm{Tr}(X^{-1} Adt)\cr
 &= \mathrm{Tr}(X^{-1} A)dt\cr
 \frac{dy}{dt}
 &=  \mathrm{Tr}(X^{-1} A)\cr
 &=  \mathrm{Tr}((At+B)^{-1} A).
\end{align}